# What measures are taken to control inductance in switching stations?

Tags: inductance, power-delivery

I was thinking about the effect of changing loads on the power grid and I'm curious about the effects of inductance, how much inductance there is, and how to prevent it from causing voltage changes at the outlet. I'm a layman.

Comment: search term : power factor correction

Comment: Substations generally have large capacitor banks that can be switched in and out as needed to compensate for power factor of the load.